# JS - Insert an object inside an object having a same data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I'm arranging series of data having a same data in it

```
var arr = [{id: 1, parent: "a"}, {id: 2, parent: "b"}];

var cArr = [
  {parentID: 1, a1: "1"}, 
  {parentID: 1, a1: "2"},
  {parentID: 2, a1: "3"},
  {parentID: 2, a1: "4"}
];
```

and I want to join them and will look like this

```
var array = [
    { id: 1, parent: "1", data: [{ a1: "1"}, { a1: "2"}] }, 
    { id: 2, parent: "2", data: [{ a1: "3"}, { a1: "4"}] }
];
```

How do I add variable like `parent` and `data` inside of object `array`?

How do I access `id: 1, parent: "1", data: [{ a1: "1"}, { a1: "2"}]`? Is it like `array[0]`?

I'm new to JS and like this if I have errors I'm so sorry. I'm `using console.log()` to check things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```js
var array = [{ parent: "1", data: [{ a1: "1"}, { a1: "2"}] }, 
               {parent: "2", data: [{ a1: "3"}, { a1: "4"}] 
}];

console.log(array[0].parent); // 1
console.log(array[0].data) // [{ a1: "1"}, { a1: "2"}]
```

To add an item just do like this using **.push** method

```
array.push({ parent: "3", data: [{ a1: "5"}, { a1: "6"}] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the `arr` with `Array.map()`, and create a new object with the content of the original object using object spread. To get the respective items from `cArr` use `Array.slice()` with the index of the current item:

```js
const arr = [{parent: "1"}, {parent: "2"}];
const cArr = [{a1: "1"}, {a1: "2"}, {a1: "3"}, {a1: "4"}];

const result = arr.map((o, i) => ({
  ...o, // copy the original object's content
  data: cArr.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2) // slice the sub-array from cArr
}));

console.log(result);
```